# How to detect XNA version at runtime?

Tags: .net, xna, assemblies, version

I have a launcher/updater application written for .NET 2.0 that needs to check if the user has XNA 4.0 installed.

If it's not, then user is asked to install it.

How to do it?

Comment: I would recommend using another language then C# for the install (C++ maybe).  The computer you are installing on is as likely to have C# runtime on it as the XNA runtime.  Maybe try a free installer program, with a script?

Comment: Two things to look at: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/562/2828.aspx#2828 A InnoInstaller script that you might consider.  Also `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0` might be the registry key you are looking for.

Comment: The installer is written with NSIS. The updater however downloads updated files from the server whenever user runs the launcher. The latest update is upgrading from XNA 3.1 to XNA 4.0 and I need to inform my users about the changed requirements.

.NET 2.0 is pre-installed since Vista (and around 2/3 of windows machines out there are Vista or better). XNA 4.0 is not pre-installed on any windows version.

Comment: Look at the registry key I posted in my answer, that should do it.  That (and the other names, v3.0, v2.0) should exist only if it is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for .NET dependencies before launching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196046/checking-for-net-dependencies-before-launching)

Comment: Please note that XNA 4.0 requires .NET 4.0 (whereas older versions of XNA targeted the older .NET 2.0 runtime).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote to do this:

```
    public string CheckXNAFramework(out bool ok)
    {
        string output = "";

        string baseKeyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XNA\Game Studio";
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey installedFrameworkVersions = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(baseKeyName);

        string[] versionNames = installedFrameworkVersions.GetSubKeyNames();

        bool found = false;
        foreach (string s in versionNames)
        {
            if (s == "v4.0")
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            output += "Microsoft XNA Framework found successfully.\n";
            ok = true;
        }
        else
        {
            output += "Correct version of the Microsoft XNA Framework not found. Please install version 4.0 or higher.\n";
            ok = false;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: This is not working with XNA 4.0 Refresh on Windows 8 (but I expect it not to work on any Windows with the mentioned XNA version)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I would say the easiest way to find if version 4.0 of xna is installed would be to look for the registry key. Look at [this bytes forum](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/237788-how-check-registry-key-exists) for an example of how to do it.

Also, as stated in my comments, this isn't the best solution because C# runtime isn't very widespread, meaning that your installer might not even work.  Try the oneclick installer or something similar (like the InnoInstaller).

EDIT: Feel stupid, this the the registry key to look for: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0`

Comment: Check the comments on the OP.  They give a good reason that they don't have to worry about the C# dependency, but *do* have to worry about the XNA dependency.  Also, I don't think that reg key you're describing has anything to do with XNA.